# When second domain controller is down, clients lose authentication

Tags: domain-controller

Our domain controller is on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I recently set up another server to be our second domain controller.

Whenever I take this second DC down, many of our client computers, some Win 7 some Win 10, lose their authentication.  Drives mapped to server share names become inaccessible.  Server shares can be accessed by IP only.  Users get prompted to enter their network authentication, with a message that "the system cannot contact a domain controller".  All clients are set to DHCP, all have their DNS and DHCP correctly pointed to the main DC.

When I both DCs are running, and I run nltest /dsgetdc:mydomain on one of the problematic clients, it returns with the secondary DC, not the main one.

On one of these clients, I did an IPCONFIG /release and /flushdns, rebooted, and it was fine.  Others weren't.

When I run NTDSUTIL, and connect it to our main DC, it "knows about 5 roles" - all of the following roles are assigned to itself:
Schema
Naming Master
PDC
RID
Infrastructure

When I run NTDSULTIL and connect it to the secondary DC, it provides the exact same information - it "knows about 5 roles", each one points to the main DC.

Why are clients getting disconnect / de-authenticated when the second DC goes down?

Many thanks!!
Matthew

Comment: Assuming that both DC's are also DNS servers for AD, have you added the new DC as a Secondary DNS server on all of the clients? Also, what are the DNS client settings on the DC's themselves?

Comment: Both servers running DNS.  Unclear how to add new DC as a 2nd DNS on clients, they get that through DHCP,..

Main DC DNS points to 8.8.8.8

2nd DC points to main DC 

More relevant info: 

On some clients, when I run echo %logonserver% - it returns the 2nd DC's name.

When I run nltest /dsgetdc:ourdomain it returns the second DC's name and address.

When I run NSLOOKUP, and set type=all, then _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.OURDOMAIN – here’s what it outputs:

Priority = 0
Weight = 100
Port = 389
Svr hostname = the 2nd DC.OURDOMAIN
the 2nd DC.OURDOMAIN internet address = 192.168.X.X

Comment: Are my SRV records not right?  I’m looking at this page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816587/how-to-verify-that-srv-dns-records-have-been-created-for-a-domain-cont

and in the instructions to verify that the appropriate zones and resource records are created, our main DC does not have SRV records where these instructions say it should.